# Numpy: Create sine wave with exponential decay

Tags: python, numpy, trigonometry

I'm a Numpy newbie.

I'd like to create an array with a million numbers, that has a sine wave with exponential decay on the amplitude.

In other words, I want the value of each cell `n` to be `sin(n) * 2 ** (-n * factor)`.

What would be the most efficient way to do that?

Comment: With all due respect to both sides (the asker & the authors of either of answers provided )IMHO there is **one cardinal piece of information missing** -- i.e. What is the exact measure of the requested ***"efficiency"*** : Is it a speed alone ( in case the O/P goes into fight inside the [TIME]-domain )? Is it a memory footprint, in case the fight goes inside the [SPACE]-domain and imacts from problem scaling start to hurt us? Or is it some form of a double-trouble, if we fight in both [TIME] and [SPACE] domains, once working with data-scales beyond the schoolbook sizes of 1E6, 1E9, 1E12, 1E15+

Comment: Hmm, I think I would care about both time and space.

Comment: @cool-RR sure,this is the most common fight.Guess you'll express that in the Question. **What is the fastest way, yet having the smallest memory-footprint to do this for 1E9, 1E12 and 1E15 data-points respectively?** Apollo navigation computer was cute enough to make it inside a 2k*16b write-able storage, having but 24 blocks of 1k*16b sized pre-wired ferrite-tori ROM-blocks with code/tables. Salute MIT, **salute Ms. Margaret HAMILTON**, the very woman, that has saved the Moon-landing overloaded AGC computer by smart designed operating system **exactly 50 years ago** The Mars is yet waiting...

Comment: If you are willing to use another module in addition to `numpy` then @max9111's answer is the best and you should accept it. That answer is the best in time and probably also in memory usage.

Answer (score 3):

Numpy has its own `sin` function, which is efficient at the task you want to do. The main cause of inefficiency would be in the exponentiation `2 ** (-n * factor)`.

However, numpy does have efficient exponentiation in its `exp` function. So we can transform the base to `e` to use `exp` by using

```
exp(-n * factor * log(2))
```

where `log` is another numpy function and uses base `e`. You could speed up your code even more by doing as much of the calculation as possible outside the loop that numpy sets up in its vectorization. In other words, you first set up the scalar

```
newfactor = -np.log(2) * factor
```

and set up your `x` array using `x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000000)` or something similar. Then your `y` array is created with

```
y = np.sin(x) * np.exp(newfactor * x)
```

Now `y` is an array with all the calculated values corresponding to the values in the `x` array.

Numpy does the looping itself, very efficiently for current technology. My experiments show that doing the exponentiation this way takes less than 1/5th the time that `np.power(2, -factor * x)` or `2 ** (-x * factor)` or `np.exp2(-x * factor)` take. Looking at the entire expression, for `x` an array of length one million, my code takes a total of `29.2 ms` to execute. The code of @ComplicatedPhenomenon, which does look good, takes a total of `81.3 ms` to execute, which is almost 3 times as long. (A hat-tip to @ComplicatedPhenomenon for pointing out an error in my code--I have corrected it and it seems to work well now.)

Comment: I understand, looks good. I wonder about one thing though: Isn't it wasteful to create 2 arrays, which might be very large, just to produce 1 array at the end? Does Numpy provide a more efficient way to do it without creating the redundant array?

Comment: I am not sure how numpy works internally. I do know it uses a large amount of "vectorization," which calculates things in an order that works well with modern CPUs and caches and memory. As far as I know, the `dot` and `sin` and `exp` in my code may not be executed separately but may be combined in one pass through the `x` array so that there are no redundant arrays. A numpy expert could say better.

Comment: @RoryDaulton  Thanks for your detailed explanation.  did you notice `y` is a number at last, not a list of numbers?

Comment: @ComplicatedPhenomenon: Oops, you are correct. Thanks for the tip! I tried to improve my code but I mis-remembered just what `np.dot` does. I have removed the `np.dot` and checked my code and it works now, even if a little slower. But correct is more important that fast!

Answer (score 1):

### You can use Numexpr

Numpy has efficient implementations for simple operations like sin(array), exp(array),.. The problem is that each expression (`sin(n); -n * factor, 2 ** previous_Temp_array`) is done on its own using temporary arrays for intermediate results. This leads to a quite high memory footprint and also has a negative impact on performance.

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
import numexpr as ne

def orig(n_max,factor):
    n=np.arange(n_max)
    return np.sin(n) * 2 ** (-n * factor)

#Rory Daulton's solution
def mod(n_max,factor):
    n=np.arange(n_max)
    newfactor = -np.log(2) * factor
    return np.sin(n) * np.exp(newfactor * n)

def mod_2(n_max,factor):
    n=np.arange(n_max)
    return ne.evaluate("sin(n) * 2**(-n * factor)")

#Rory Daulton's solution using Numexpr
def mod_3(n_max,factor):
    n=np.arange(n_max)
    newfactor = -np.log(2) * factor
    return ne.evaluate("sin(n) * exp(newfactor * n)")
```

**Timings**

```
%timeit res=orig(1e6,0.5)
81 ms ± 4.75 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit res=mod(1e6,0.5)
46.3 ms ± 5.29 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit res=mod_2(1e6,0.5)
16 ms ± 214 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit res=mod_3(1e6,0.5)
11.1 ms ± 48.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: This is indeed an excellent answer, though the questioner implies that he/she wants to use `numpy` while this answer also uses another module, `numexpr`. However, `numexpr` is fairly common--for example, it is included and installed in the Anaconda distribution of Python. I consider this the best answer, better than mine, so +1!